# How to pass the loop values into string separated by comma in javascript

Tags: javascript

In the below code I am fetching the values which will select in "Right Side Box" (i.e one, two,three).

```
___________      __________

    four   |    |

           |>   |one

    five   |<   |two

           | >> |three

           |<<  |
                __________
```

Code is:

```
function Selected()
{

    var menu = document.getElementById('selectedServersID').length;
    alert(menu);
    for (var i=0; i<menu; i++)
    {

        var selectedcol = document.getElementById('selectedServersID')[i].value;
        //var selectedcol = document.getElementById('selectedServersID')[i].innerHTML;
        alert(selectedcol);

    }

}
```

The above code fetches all the values present in the rightside box. Now,I need to get all the values from the "For loop" and need to add to the string separated by Comma. out side the for loop how to create the string and store all the values separated by comma? plz help.

Comment: have a var declared outside the for loop and inside the loop
colString=colString+selectedcol+",";
finally just remove the last ,

Comment: are you using the result of getElementById as an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how:

```
var menu = document.getElementById('selectedServersID').length;
alert(menu);
var result = "";
for (var i=0; i<menu; i++){
    var selectedcol = document.getElementById('selectedServersID')[i].value;
    alert(selectedcol);

    if(i>0){
       result += ','; 
    }
    result += selectedcol;
}
alert(result);
```

Comment: Hi roblovelock, THANK YOU VERY MUCH.. :-) . Code worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function Selected()
{
    var menu = document.getElementById('selectedServersID').length;
    var result = new Array();
    for (var i=0; i<menu; i++)
    {
        var selectedcol = document.getElementById('selectedServersID')[i].value;
        result.push(selectedcol);
    }
    return result.join(',');
}
```